.sqlproj building and deployment workflow
I'm looking for the proper workflow to deploy an SQL Server without any manual action.
I have a folder where I describe how an SQL Server's Database should look like, by that I mean .sql files which create tables, roles, etc.

At this point, we have a .sln file generated by Visual Studio, which is not used for any other reason than building a solution file .sln which build a .dacpac, so ideally, I 'd like to get rid of it.
I want to use the Azure Data Studio to generate an .sqlproj file which contains info about what folders contain the .sql files that need to be used in order to build the .dacpac file and then deploy it to a sql database.
The problem is that if you decide to add a folder with new tables you need to re-build the .sln (or, is that possible: run the .sql scripts (as queries) against a dev database in order to be registered by the database and these changes to be reflected in the .sqlproj file when it is built by the corresponding pipeline step.)
Pipeline looks like that (Build and Deployment of DACPAC via Azure DevOps Pipeline without .sln (or any artifact)):
variables:
  ARMSvcCnnName: YourAzureResourceManagerServiceConnectionName
  AzureSQLServerName: YourAzureSQLSeverName
  AzureSQLDBName: YourAzureSQLDBName
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build DACPAC from SQL Database Project'
  inputs:
    solution: '**\*.sqlproj'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: 'Deploy Azure SQL DB'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(ARMSvcCnnName)'
    AuthenticationType: 'servicePrincipal'
    ServerName: '$(AzureSQLServerName).database.windows.net'
    DatabaseName: '$(AzureSQLDBName)'
    deployType: 'DacpacTask'
    DeploymentAction: 'Publish'
    DacpacFile: '**\*.dacpac'
    AdditionalArguments: '/v:ETLUserPassword="$(sql-password)" /v:AppUserPassword="$(sql-password)"'
    IpDetectionMethod: 'AutoDetect'
    DeleteFirewallRule: false

At this point we need to build the solution to get the updates which I like to get rid of.
So, as I see it up to now:
Let's say I have an empty db and I have created an .sqlproj using:

Empty Azure Database
Generate .sqlproj file using Azure Data Studio
Place it in my repo
Trigger the pipeline (finds .sqlproj and deploys an empty database to the empty database`)

Ideal way of working:

Edit folder in the repo
Pipeline finds out about the changes
Generates a new .sqlproj
Builds .sqlproj
Deploy to the Azure Sql Database


Hi @Potis23, Nice to work with you again. But may I know why you would like pipeline to generate .sqlproj? As we discussed, it should be pushed to cloud repo as the source code of your SQL DB project for pipeline to build. May I ask which document you are following to ask pipeline to generate .sqlproj? The developers rather than the pieline should take care of the source code and push them to Azure Repos, shouldn't they?

If any change happens in the .sqlproj file from your local repo, you can simply push the change commit(s) to cloud Azure Repo, so that the pipeline will first download the latest version of your code from cloud repo onto agent and then build that version of .sqlproj. Is this what concerns you in this post?

Hi again @ALvin, thanks for your reply. I was investigating if it is possible to automate the build stage of the db project. I ll probably delete my thread as per your comment

Hi @Potis23, I think it is totally OK to share your queries in this post as there are always users in our community who are new to SQL DB project and Azure DevOps. The workflow in query is just not recommended and not the best practice. And we always have different questions throughout the journey of a new exploration, right? Good luck with the trip to go and appreciate your sharing and efforts.

Given the consideration that we are new to use SQL DB project, please be advised NOT to generate the .sqlproj with pipelines.
As a better practice, the developers should bring the changes in .sqlproj by pushing the commits from local workspace into cloud repo as the source code.
Instead of dealing with the source code, the pipeline should take care of the rest, that is to build our SQL DB project and then deploy the generated .dacpac artifact to Azure SQL server DB.
